# How to restrict the size of lists within Pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Given a Pandas `Dataframe` consisting of a column (`ColumnB`) with **lists having varying number of elements**, how can we restrict the list to have, say, the first `2` elements?

```
      ColumnA       ColumnB
0.                  ['hey', 'hello' ,'great',....]
1                   ['USA', 'UK' ,'Germany',....]
2
3
4
...
```

The expected output would be like this (restricting the lists in `ColumnB` to at most `2` elements)

```
      ColumnA       ColumnB
0.                  ['hey', 'hello']
1                   ['USA', 'UK']
2
3
4
...
```

Thanks for any suggestions/advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnB'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])
```

Here the lambda will slice only first two elements. Incase if you have list which length is less than 2 add the condition then perform Slicing.

Answer (score 1):

Because `str` working with iterables for first 2 values use indexing with `str`:

```
df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnB'].str[:2]
```